# Using angular-ui-select with angular seed project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select, angular-seed

I created a base project from https://github.com/angular/angular-seed and I'm trying to use angular-ui-select to add dropdown menus to this project. I installed angular-ui-select and added select.js and select.css to my index.html file. Angular-sanitize is also installed.

My view1.html looks like :

```
 <p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>
<ui-select ng-model="vm.person.selected" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in vm.people">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

And my controller looks like :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute','myApp.testDirective', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.people = [
   { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 10 },
   { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 },
   { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30 },
   { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 31 },
   { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefanía@email.com', age: 16 },
   { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54 },
   { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43 },
   { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21 }
 ];
}]);
```

Attached is a pic of what I'm currently seeing. Not sure why it's not displaying properly.[image]

Comment: Could you create a plunkr or jsbin to demo this?

Comment: Could you create at least a repo on github so we can see the entire project?

Comment: https://github.com/erichardson30/ui-select-demo @ViníciusFagundes

Comment: @MicahWilliamson added github link above

Comment: why did you create a second question with exactly the same content? also the same guy below answers in both questions..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678915/angular-ui-select-not-displaying ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a css issue. Believe or not. You need to add bootstrap 3:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
```